# Trouble getting relative layout right

Tags: android, android-layout

I have been pulling my hair out trying to get my relative layout setup the way I want.  I want to have a `EditText` on the left with a `TextView` in the middle and a `Button` to the right and all those over a `ListView` Here is as close as I can get [image: I have gotten] ...

Here is the xml I am using:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/new_bookmark_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/new_bookmark_clock"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/new_bookmark_clock"
        android:layout_width="12sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_add_new_bookmark"
        android:text="@string/xx_xx_xx" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_add_new_bookmark"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/add" />

     <ListView
         android:id="@+id/bookmark_list"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_below="@+id/new_bookmark_name" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: ` android:layout_width="12sp"`?

Comment: you want like this? http://postimg.org/image/xrc0nhvrv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/new_bookmark_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/new_bookmark_clock"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btn_add_new_bookmark"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="text" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/new_bookmark_clock"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btn_add_new_bookmark"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_add_new_bookmark"
    android:text="@string/xx_xx_xx" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_add_new_bookmark"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/add" />

 <ListView
     android:id="@+id/bookmark_list"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_below="@+id/new_bookmark_name" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can better achieve it through LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/new_bookmark_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/new_bookmark_clock"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/new_bookmark_clock"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_add_new_bookmark"
        android:text="@string/xx_xx_xx" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_add_new_bookmark"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/add" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/new_bookmark_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/new_bookmark_clock"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:text="XXXXXXXXX" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_add_new_bookmark"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:text="Add" />
 </LinearLayout>

 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/bookmark_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/new_bookmark_name" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with below
change `android:layout_width="12sp"` to   `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/new_bookmark_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/new_bookmark_clock"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/new_bookmark_clock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_add_new_bookmark"
        android:text="xx_xx_xx" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_add_new_bookmark"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="add" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/bookmark_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/new_bookmark_name" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you were providing fixed width to `Textview` which create problem, I just added one more `Relative Layout which achieve your goal, have a look below code`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/new_bookmark_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/new_bookmark_clock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/new_bookmark_name"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="xx_xx_xx" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_add_new_bookmark"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent=""
        android:text="add" />

    </RelativeLayout>

     <ListView
         android:id="@+id/bookmark_list"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_below="@+id/layout" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/new_bookmark_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/new_bookmark_clock"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/xx_xx_xx" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_add_new_bookmark"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/add" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/bookmark_list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/new_bookmark_name" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try it like this , this way it keeps your top_bar seperate from list view . Also for textview never use dp . Sp is used for text size.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
 android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:id ="@+id/top_bar">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/new_bookmark_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/new_bookmark_clock"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="text" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/new_bookmark_clock"
    android:layout_width="12sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_add_new_bookmark"
    android:text="@string/xx_xx_xx" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_add_new_bookmark"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/add" />

 </RelativeLayout

 <ListView
     android:id="@+id/bookmark_list"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  />
```

Comment: well to achieve what given in the above image i would prefer to keep the top 3 view in a seperate relative layout and then provide a listview. Since i am using a Linear layout as root layout with orientation vertical listview would always be below the top_bar. If you wanna use relative layout as root layout you can give the listview android:layout_below="@+id/top_bar"